# Making changes to style variables of Quasar

Tags: vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

I have a project using Vite, Vue, Quasar, Sass, and TypeScript.

The pages are loading, routers are working, and there are no errors or problems.

However, I have trouble achieving something that seems very basic: the predefined `h1` style has a size of `6rem` and I'd like to bring it down a bit, to say `4rem`.

I've tried editing `quasar-variables.sass` and doing something like this:

```
$h1: map-merge($h1, (size: 4rem, line-height: 4rem))
```

This doesn't work, because `$h1` is unknown at this point.

What does work is including a full line like:

```
$h1: (size: 4rem, line-height: 4rem, letter-spacing: -.01562em, weight: 300)
```

This is copying the entire line from `quasar/src/css/variables.sass` and just making the changes I need. It works, but it's clearly not the right way to go - I don't want to copy all kinds of attributes I don't have an opinion on, just to change one or two others.

I've tried `@import`ing the `variables.sass` at the start of the `quasar-variables.sass` file but that causes whatever changes I make to be ignored (even the one that does work without the import).

I've tried `@use`ing the file instead, but that doesn't make `$h1` available.

What (surely obvious) solution am I missing here?

Is the problem that I am using Vite to build and run a dev server perhaps, and if so, what do I need to change?

If I should be going about updating the style in an entirely different way, please feel free to suggest. I could of course just old-school load an extra .css over the top, but I was looking for something a bit more in line with the frameworks used.